# Convert zsh loop into sh syntax

Tags: sh, zsh

A while ago I wrote this loop in a `zsh` script, and now I don't remember what it does, and I need to convert this script to run in `sh`.

```sh
for f in ${HOME}/.dotfiles/files/*(N) ${HOME}/.dotfiles/files/.*(N); do
    symlink_prompt $(basename $f)
done
```

Can someone help me understand what this does, and how I can duplicate it in `sh` syntax?

Comment: Hi perhaps `for f in .* *; do  symlink_prompt $(basename $f) ; done`

Comment: @MichaelDorst : Unfortunately, Posix shell does not have an equivalent to the `(N)` modifier of zsh. You can leave out the modifier, but if you have no matches for the pattern, you will get an message on stderr, and you will need to test inside the loop for the existence of the file. Also, in Posix shell you need to write `$(basename "$f")`, just in case `f` contains white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glob qualifier `(N)` causes the pattern to disappear entirely should it fail to match any files. There is no directly equivalent in POSIX shell; instead, you should simply check if `f` actually exists and continue if it does not. (If the pattern fails to match any files, `f` takes the literal pattern as its value instead.)

```
for f in "$HOME"/.dotfiles/files/* "$HOME"/.dotfiles/files/.*; do
  [ -e "$f" ] || continue
  symlink_prompt "$(basename "$f")"
done
```

If you are actually using `bash`, you can set the `nullglob` option instead.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in "$HOME"/.dotfiles/files/* "$HOME"/.dotfiles/files/.*; do
  symlink_prompt "$(basename "$f")"
done
```

Comment: I love that `[ -e "$f" ] || continue` line. The fact that && and || as control structures is idiomatic in shell scripting is just crazy to me.

Comment: Well, that's what they are. They *aren't* boolean operators, and shell doesn't *have* boolean values, so they're free for other uses.

Comment: Turns out this isn't perfectly equivalent, because `"$HOME"/.dotfiles/files/.*` will match `.` and `..`.

Comment: I asked about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928816/avoid-matching-and-when-looping-through-files-in-posix-shell