# Avoid matching . and .. when looping through files in POSIX shell

Tags: sh

I want to do something to every file in a directory, so I have

```sh
for f in /path/* /path/.*; do
  [ -e "$f" ] || continue
  do_thing "$f"
done
```

Unfortunately, this also matches `.` and `..`, which is undesirable in this case. How can I avoid matching `.` and `..`?

Comment: Just use `grep -v "^.{1,2}$"`

Comment: @Andra could you explain a little more of what that means? I see that `-v` is invert match, but that regex pattern doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Specifically the `{1,2}` part, what are `1` and `2`?

Comment: it means one or two. but I believe the regexp is not correct for all greps. flags might have to be `-vE` for {1,2} to work

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. For others not well versed in regex, `^` matches the start of the string, `.` matches any non-whitespace character, and `{1,2}` means either one or two of the preceding characters. `$` is the end of the string, so all together this matches `.` and `..`. `-v` inverts the match, so you get everything but those.

Comment: yeah, I just noticed, that you exclude also all one and two letter files. it must be `grep -vE "^\.{1,2}$"`

Comment: `.` matches any character, including whitespace.

Comment: Also, where do I put that grep? After in? Do I do `for f in ls -a | grep -vE "^.{1,2}$"; do`?

Comment: enclose the ls ... $" in backticks `, and also don't forget the backslash before the dot

Comment: One of you guys want to post all this as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I will post the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run `do_thing` on every file in the current directory, try:

```
find /path -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec do_thing {} \;
```

This method avoids looping and avoids parsing `ls`.

#### How it works

- `find /path`

  This starts a `find` command and tells find to look in directory `/path`.
- `-maxdepth 1`

  This tells `find` to look only in the current directory and not to descend into subdirectories.
- `-type f`

  This tells `find` that we are only looking for regular files (not directories).
- `-exec do_thing {} \;`

  This runs command `do_thing` on every file found.

Comment: I actually like your solution better than mine because it doesn't rely on string matching or wildcard expansion

Comment: Also what are `{}` and `\;` for?

Comment: I found out from another post that `{}` is where the results of `find` are inserted into your command. Still not quite sure why the semicolon has to be escaped though.

Comment: @MichaelDorst `-exec` can be used to do many things.  For one, `do_thing` is not limited to a simple command.  It can be a complicated script filled with many commands.  There are other options.

Comment: @MichaelDorst `find` needs to know where the `-exec` command ends and that is what the escaped semicolon `\;` marks.  This is important because, in more complex cases, one can have more arguments to `find` __after__ the `-exec` command.  (One may even have several `-exec` commands in a single `find` command.)   If the semicolon wasn't escaped, it would be treated as the end of the `find` command instead of the end of `-exec`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `if` to avoid them?

```
tmp_path=/path
for f in $tmp_path/* $tmp_path/.*; do
  if [ "$f" == "$tmp_path/." ] || [ "$f" == "$tmp_path/.." ]
  then
    continue
  fi
  [ -e "$f" ] || continue
  echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: Don't use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for your variables. Those are used by the shell itself (e.g. `PATH`, `RANDOM`) or by the system (e.g. `HOME`).

Comment: I considered this, although I thought there might be a simpler (or maybe just more "elegant") way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

the following should match all the hidden files and exclude both `.` and `..`

```
for f in `ls -a /path | grep -vE "^\.{1,2}$"`; do
    # whatever
done
```

`-v` inverts the match, `\.` matches the literal dot, `{1,2}` matches it once or twice, `^` and `$` match the start and end of line, respectively. the `-E` flag makes the `{m,n}` syntax work. The backticks ` prevent the shell choking on the pipe. (hihi)

Answer (score 1):

```
clean_path=`ls -a ~/example_dir/ | grep -v -P "^\.{1,2}$"`
for f in $clean_path; do
    do_thing $f;
done
```

`ls -a ~/some_dir` command to print out all of the file in the `some_dir` directory.

`^\.{1,2}$` means, match a string which start (`^`) with dot (`\.`), the dot may come in 1 to 2 characters (`{1,2}`), and that's the end of the string (`$`), so it will match both `.` and `..`.

Using backtick within a command means "process the result of this command".

`grep -v -P`, `-v` flag to inverse the answer, so it would exclude the matching file that named `.` and `..`. `-P` flag to use the Perl regular expression.

Voila, you can now iterate them since the result is only separated by space.